# Azure resourceManager

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to scale programmatically an Azure worker role and I can't find the right syntax for the resource name.

```
 // Create the autoscale client.
 AutoscaleClient autoscaleClient = new AutoscaleClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert));
 AutoscaleSettingGetResponse get =autoscaleClient.Settings.Get(AutoscaleResourceIdBuilder.BuildCloudServiceResourceId("WRK-GROUP-NE01","CIW.GROUPS",true) );
 AutoscaleSetting setting = get.Setting;
```

It returns : ResourceNotFound: The resource service name monitoring is not supported.
Can you point me to the right syntax?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide which you're following is based on the Azure Service Management model, aka Classic mode, which is deprecated and only exists mainly for backward compatibility support.

You should use the latest Microsoft.Azure.Insights nuget package for getting the autoscale settings.

Sample code using the nuget above is as below:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights;
using Microsoft.Rest;

//... Get necessary values for the required parameters 

var client = new InsightsManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(token));
client.AutoscaleSettings.Get(resourceGroupName, autoScaleSettingName);
```

See the REST API Reference below for getting the autoscale settings.

```
GET
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/autoscaleSettings/{autoscale-setting-name}?api-version={api-version}
```

For updating Autosale setting you can use below api

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/{autoscaleSettingName}?api-version=2015-04-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/autoscalesettings/createorupdate

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works. However the mentioned api does not get the status of the Cloudservice (running, transitioning, etc). This is to avoid to send a rescale command if the cloudservice is not in a running state (ie still processing a previous autscale command).